# Check if element exists in the DOM, and if not, insert it

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Say I have the following html:

```
<div id="list">
    <span id="one">toto</span> 
    <span id="two">titi</span>
</div>
```

and somehow, I have retrieved a list of **ids** + **contents** in json which is as follows:

```
var retrievedList = [
{
"id" : "one",
"content" : "toto"
},
{"id" : "two",
 "content" : "titi"
},
{
"id" : "three",
"content" : "tutu"
}];
```

Notice the **third element** is not yet in the DOM.

**I want to use JS/JQuery in order to check if there exists an element in the retrieved list that is not in the DOM/HTML and if that is the case, insert a corresponding span into the DOM/Html.**

What is the best way to achieve this in JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.each(retrievedList, function(i, v) {
    if(!$('#' + v.id).length) {
        $('<span />').prop('id', v.id).text(v.content).appendTo('#list');
    }
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dAMbp/1/)

Comment: Thanks for this relevant and lighting fast reply!